# Image button is not functioning anymore after click outside it's area - libgdx - scene2d

Tags: java, user-interface, libgdx, scene2d

I'm trying to build a menu screen using Scene2d. The screen have an image background, an image button and a dialog that shows the highest score. I've managed to make scaling fit with different screen size, but the play button will just works only if the first touch or click is on it otherwise it will become invisible with touching or clicking after the first click or touch to the screen. I'm will be very grate full if anyone show me the problem :p.

Here is the main part my code

```
private Table buildControlsLayer(){
    Table layer = new Table();
    layer.center();
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog("HighSocre: " + highScore, skinSea);
    dialog.setColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    dialog.setOrigin(Align.center);
    dialog.setScale(1.5f);
    layer.add(dialog).padBottom(100);
    layer.row();
    btnPlay = new Button(skinSea, "play");
    layer.add(btnPlay);
    btnPlay.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
            onPlayClicked();
        }
    });
    layer.setFillParent(true);
    return layer;
}

private void rebuildStage(){
    atlas = new TextureAtlas(Constants.TEXTURE_ATLAS_UI);
    skinSea = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal(Constants.SKIN_SEA_UI), atlas);

    imgBackground = new Image(skinSea, "BackGround");
    imgBackground.setFillParent(true);
    layerControl = buildControlsLayer();

    stage.clear();
    stage.addActor(imgBackground);
    stage.addActor(layerControl);
    stage.setDebugAll(true);
}

@Override public void show() {
    stage = new Stage(new ExtendViewport(Constants.VIEWPORT_WIDTH, Constants.VIEWPORT_HEIGHT));
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    rebuildStage();
    this.resize(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    Gdx.input.setCatchBackKey(true);
}

@Override public void resize(int w, int h) {
    stage.getViewport().update(w, h, false);
    imgBackground.setSize(w, h);
}

@Override public void render(float deltaTime){
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    stage.act(deltaTime);
    stage.draw();
}
```

Btw, initially I created a table that contain the background image, I set the table's size to the size of the screen and had it `setFillParent(true)`, but the background was not in it right position. I tried to set the table position, not `setFillParent(true)` and tried to set it's size to the right size, but the background image was always not in it right position or it was have a bad scale. I managed to fix this by not add the image to a table but add it directly to the stage. Pls show me the way to use a table that contain a background image if you know how to.